# Updating solr index with deleted records

Tags: solr

I was trying to figure out how to update the index for the deleted records. I'm indexing from the database. I search for documents in the database, put them in an array and index them by creating a `SolrInputDocument`.

So, I couldn't figure out how to update the index for the deleted records (because they don't exist in the database now).

I'm using the [php-solr-pecl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the deletion of the documents separately from Solr.
Solr won't handle it for you.
In case of Incremental, You need to maintain the Documents deleted from the Database and then fire a delete query for the same to clean up the index.
For this you have to maintain a timestamp and delete flag to identify the documents.
In case of the Full, you can just clean up the index and reindex all.
However, in case of failures you may loose all the data.

Solr DIH provides a bit of handling for the same

Answer (score 0):

create a delete trigger on the database table which will insert the deleted record id in another table.(or have `boolean` field "`deleted`" and mark the record instead of actually deleting it, considering the trade-offs I would choose the trigger)

Once in a while do a batch delete on index based on the "deleted" table, also removing them from the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue and came up with batch deletion approach.

We created a program that will delete the document from SOLR based on the uniqueid, if the unique id is present in SOLR but not in database you can delete that document from SOLR.

(Get the uniqueid list from SOLR) minus (uniqueid list from database)

You can just use SQL minus to get the list of uniqueid belonging to the documents that needs to be deleted.

Else you can do everything in JAVA side. Get the list from database, get the list from solr.. Do a comparison between the 2 list and delete based on that..This would be lost faster for huge number of documents. You can use binary search method to do the comparison..

Something like

```
Collections.binarySearch(DatabaseUniqueidArray, "SOLRuniqueid");
```